# How to build android apk using javafxports,opencv3.4, gradle and eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, build.gradle, javafxports

I use OpenSource *javafxports plugins* to build a desktop and android application using *gradle* buildtool with eclipse.

For android I can generate APK and upon unzip in */lib* folder there are no native libraries.

My question is: How to build with the Android and can is use same `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);` to load native libraries?

If so where should I place ABI.so files in the project and how to include in the build gradle?

I was using this project structure and build.gradle:

[image: Click here]

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by converting  /lib folder to jar and include in the build. native libraries are packaged into APK directly under /lib folder with ABI.